# Only consider values when available in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I am working on a simple GUI on Tkinter. What I want is add up all the filled blanks, if there are. If there are empty fields, just take them as “0”.

[image]

However it’s not successful and the problem lies on:

```
value2 = float(c.get())
```

the error is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Here is the codes:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk


def plus(*args):
    value = float(a.get())
    value1 = float(b.get())
    if c:
        value2 = float(c.get())
    else:
        value2 == float(0.0)
    if d:
        value3 = float(d.get())
    else:
        value3 == float(0.0)

    result.set(value + value1 + value2 + value3)

root = Tk()
root.title("Plus them")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10 10 10 10")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

a = StringVar()
b = StringVar()
c = StringVar()
d = StringVar()
result = StringVar()

feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=a)
feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

feet_entry1 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=b)
feet_entry1.grid(column=5, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

feet_entry2 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=c)
feet_entry2.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E), pady = 5)

feet_entry3 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=d)
feet_entry3.grid(column=5, row=2, sticky=(W, E), pady = 5)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="the result is").grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = result).grid(column=5, row=3, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Plus", command=plus).grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=W)

feet_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', plus)
root.mainloop()
```

I think the problem lies in the function defining part. And I tried below:

```
def plus(*args):
    try:
        value = float(a.get())
        value1 = float(b.get())
        value2 = float(c.get())
        value3 = float(d.get())

        result.set(value + value1 + value2 + value3)

    except ValueError:
        pass
```

but it doesn't help. What’s the way to put them correctly?

Comment: `if c:` and `if d:` don't make sense. They are always True, since `c` and `d` are StringVars. Try `if c.get():` to check if the string is not empty. Also you should use a single = in `value2 == float(0.0)`. Or just use `value2 = 0.0` since 0.0 already is a float.

Comment: @fhdrsdg, marvelous!! it works. would you mind make it an answer so that everybody have a direct look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c.get() doesn't always return something like "0.02", it will return "" if there is no user input, in this case it will throw an exceptiong showing error to transfer "" to float. so I modified your code, added something to check the user input.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk


def inputToFloat(input):
    if isinstance(input, float):
        return input
    elif isinstance(input, basestring):
        input = input.strip()
        return 0.0 if not input else float(input)
    else:
        raise Exception("unsupported type")

def plus(*args):
    value = inputToFloat(a.get())
    value1 = inputToFloat(b.get())
    if c:
        value2 = inputToFloat(c.get())
    else:
        value2 == inputToFloat(0.0)
    if d:
        value3 = inputToFloat(d.get())
    else:
        value3 == inputToFloat(0.0)

    result.set(value + value1 + value2 + value3)

root = Tk()
root.title("Plus them")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10 10 10 10")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

a = StringVar()
b = StringVar()
c = StringVar()
d = StringVar()
result = StringVar()

feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=a)
feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

feet_entry1 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=b)
feet_entry1.grid(column=5, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

feet_entry2 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=c)
feet_entry2.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E), pady = 5)

feet_entry3 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=d)
feet_entry3.grid(column=5, row=2, sticky=(W, E), pady = 5)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="the result is").grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = result).grid(column=5, row=3, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Plus", command=plus).grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=W)

feet_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', plus)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you so much. I need time to digest the answer.

Comment: the float() function will throw a ValueError if the input could not be transferred to a float. so in this case, you need to detect it manually.

Comment: why do you call `inputToFloat(0.0)`? You're converting a float to a float, which is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

with fhdrsdg's advise, it's changed to below and it works.

```
def plus(*args):
    value = float(a.get())
    value1 = float(b.get())
    if c.get():
        value2 = float(c.get())
    else:
        value2 = 0.0
    if d.get():
        value3 = float(d.get())
    else:
        value3 = 0.0

    result.set(value + value1 + value2 + value3)
```